# Android Studio 1.0 can't continue Setup

Tags: android

I am on a Macbook Pro with Yosemity running. When accepted the license agreement in the AS 1 Setup there is no possibility to go the next step, button 'next' grewed out

Answer (score 1):

You should select one of these license and agree.